# android onServiceConnected() is called in a separate thread?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

I have been looking for a clear answer for this, but couldn't find it anywhere. When an android app tries to make a connection with service and implements the ServiceConnection methods (onServiceConnected() and onServiceDisconnected()), do these callback functions run in a separate thread or in the main UI thread? Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These methods are called on the main thread. The [documentation for `ServiceConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html) clearly states that:

> Like many callbacks from the system, the methods on this class are
>   called from the main thread of your process.